# Automatic Reboot after installing SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

I'm being paranoid here I'm sure. I'm at the end of an SQL Server 2012 install and this message appears.  I know it says that I must restart the computer but I've had instances where installer automatically restarted the server when I didn't want it to. I cannot reboot this production server right now.  Am I safe to click OK to complete the installation?

[image]

Comment: In a more cautious way, I would not even install anything on a production server in the first place during a time window when no restart can be allowed. 
Some application installation may automatically initiate a reboot. So why not wait until a window when you do not mind rebooting?

Comment: The only time it can be rebooted is 3am. Since I work nowhere near that time of the night, I install the software during the day, and the server reboots on schedule at night.

Comment: No offense, but you are looking for trouble this way. I'd recommend you to tell your boss about the potential risks and as long as you have "warned" your boss, it is then not your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely click OK and it won't reboot it.  The instance will even be up, online and accessible without the reboot.

It's always good practice to reboot after a fresh installation or patches as when you try to perform another patch or installation down the road, the installer will more than likely fail of the 'Restart Required' portion of the checks.